# It seems misfire_grace_time does not work

Tags: python, apscheduler

The code I am running is as follows.

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
trigger = CronTrigger(day_of_week='0-6', hour=9, minute=12, second='0')
def job2():
    print('job2')
scheduler.add_job(func=job2, trigger=trigger, misfire_grace_time=120, id='task_two')
scheduler.start()
while True:
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    time.sleep(5)
```

The output of the program is as follows:
[image]

Why job2 function is not executed?
The current time is 09:12, and this time is within 120 seconds after the time specified by the scheduler.

Comment: can you use the logger to show more data? Should be seeing log messages like 'Run time of job 'job2 ((trigger: cron[day_of_week='0-6', hour='18', minute='46', seconds='0'], next run at: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss  TZTZ)" was missed by hh:mm:ss.ffffff'

Comment: @cowbert may i ask what is printed in the log to see the information you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The important line is this:

```
Next wakeup is due at 2020-02-22 09:12:00+0800 (in 86368.007853 seconds)
```

It seems that your local time was already past the daily scheduled time of 09:12:00, so the job was scheduled to be run on the next day. That's why you're not seeing it being executed. I don't know why but you seem to be under impression that the trigger will produce a fire time in the past as long as it's within `misfire_grace_time` of the current time. This is not how it works.